# Equivariant Submersion Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, equivariant-maps, equivariant-topology

I have a question about the *Equivariant Submersion Theorem* (Proposition 2.7) in the article *Equivariant control data and neighborhood deformation retractions* by Markus J. Pflaum and Graeme Wilkin. The statement is as follows:

**Proposition 2.7:** Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and let $f:M \to P$ be a $G$-equivariant submersion between smooth $G$-manifolds $M$ and $P$. Let $x\in M$ be a point, $H=G_x$ be the isotropy group of $x$ and $K=G_{f(x)} \supset H$ the isotropy group of
$f(x)$. Then there exist:

- a finite dimensional orthogonal  $K$-representation space $N$,
- a finite dimensional orthogonal  $H$-representation space $W$,
- a $K$-invariant open convex neighborhood of the origin $B\subset N$,
- an $H$-invariant open convex neighborhood of the origin $C\subset W$,
- $G$-equivariant open embeddings $\Theta: G\times_H (B \times C) \hookrightarrow M$ and $\Psi: G\times_K B \hookrightarrow P$

such that
$\Theta \big( [e,0]_{G\times_H (B \times C)} \big) = x$,  $\Psi \big( [e,0]_{G\times_K B}  \big) = f(x)$ and such that the following
diagram commutes, where $\pi : B \times C \to C$ is projection onto the first factor and
$\overline{\mathrm{id}_G \times \pi}$ maps $[g,(v,w)]_{G \times_H (B\times C)}$ to $[g,v]_{G\times_K B}$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
  G\times_H (B \times C) @>{\Theta}>> M\\
@V{\overline{\mathrm{id}_G \times \pi}}VV @VV{f}V\\
G\times_KB @>{\Psi}>> P.
\end{CD}

**Question:** Why can't we take $B = N$ and $C = W$?

It seems to me that we can. Indeed, in the proof Pflaum and Wilkin give, the open convex subspaces $B$ and $C$ are actually constructed as *open balls* inside $N$ resp. $W$. In particular, by scaling the radius using the function $r \mapsto \frac{r}{1-r^2}$ they are even *diffeomorphic* to $N$ and $W$, and these diffeomorphisms are $G$-equivariant as the $G$-actions on $N$ and $W$ are orthogonal. So can't we just identify $B$ and $C$ with $N$ and $W$ using these diffeomorphisms?